# Image upload require to include image into solution each time

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-upload

i have require to upload image. i have coded as follows:

```
string filename = "";
            string FilePath = "";
            filename = Path.GetFileName(FileImage.FileName);
            FilePath = Server.MapPath("./JQueryImages");
            string destPath = Path.Combine(FilePath, filename);
            FileImage.PostedFile.SaveAs(destPath);
            ViewState["ImagePath"] = destPath.ToString();
            ImgUploaded.ImageUrl = destPath;
            LblUploadMsg.Text = "Image uploaded successfully";
            LblUploadMsg.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```

image get into a folder `JQueryImages` but i have a image control `ImgUploaded` that doesn't show image while load. When i check my solution folder image doesn't get loaded. i require `to include each image` after upload.
i don't want to include each image.what can be solution to this problem.thanks for assistance.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you please reformulate what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sir, actually after upload i require to include that image into a JQueryImage folder. image show into a folder but i have to right click and include into it.

Comment: Why is your working solution file in what sounds like your production directory? It sounds like you are working in a very strange way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 string filename = "";
            string FilePath = "";
            filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            FilePath = Server.MapPath("./JQueryImages");
            string destPath = Path.Combine(FilePath, filename);
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(destPath);
            ViewState["ImagePath"] = destPath.ToString();
            Image1.ImageUrl = "~/JQueryImages/" + filename;
            Label1.Text = "Image uploaded successfully";
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```

This is a final code that i have used. It works now.